# R Optimizing for minimum value

Tags: r

I have a function that I would like to find the minimal value

```
start.capital =  2000000
target.capital = 49594660
monthly.inflation = 0.002
monthly.deposits = 50000
n.obs = 240

fn<-function(monthly.mean.return,
         start.capital,
         monthly.inflation,
         monthly.deposits,
         n.obs,
         target.capital){

  #monthly.mean.return = annual.mean.return / 12
  #monthly.inflation = annual.inflation / 12

  req = matrix(start.capital, n.obs+1, 1)
  for (a in 1:n.obs) {
    req[a + 1, ] = req[a, ] * (1 + monthly.mean.return - monthly.inflation) + monthly.deposits
  }
  ending.value=req[nrow(req),]
  value<-target.capital - ending.value
  return(value)
}
```

I would like to minimize "monthly.mean.return". The correct answer is 0.01 but I am getting big numbers...

I am trying:

```
optimize(f=fn,
     monthly.mean.return,
     start.capital,
     monthly.inflation,
     monthly.deposits,
     n.obs,
     target.capital,
     lower=0)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wording is important. You are not trying to minimize `monthly.mean.return`, you are trying to minimize `fn` with respect to `monthly.mean.return`.

First of all, your objective being to reach the `target.capital`, your `fn` function should not return `target.capital - ending.value` but rather the absolute error `abs(target.capital - ending.value)`. I hope you can see why (`optimize` is trying to make the output value of `fn` as small as possible.)

Then, you are obviously not calling the `optimize` function properly. Here is how you need to proceed to pass these pre-specified arguments:

```
optimize(f=fn, 
         start.capital = start.capital,
         monthly.inflation = monthly.inflation,
         monthly.deposits = monthly.deposits,
         n.obs = n.obs,
         target.capital = target.capital,
         lower = 0,
         upper = 1)

$minimum
[1] 0.01001939

$objective
[1] 170750.9
```